# Converting Color Profile from Adobe RGB for Reading in Skimage on Linux

Tags: colors, imagemagick

I have an image of an orange fabric, which I need to use in a program that uses the skimage library. The full file is here: https://storage.googleapis.com/color-mapping/src-colors/poly/Orange.tif

If I write a program that simply reads in the image and writes it, like follows:

```
from skimage import io
img = io.imread(path)
io.imsave(outpath, img)
```

The image that comes out appears to have dulled colors compared to the original when viewed on my OS X computer.

On OS X, I have found a command which appears to transform the image in such a way that the problem no longer appears to occur:

```
sips -m /System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/sRGB Profile.icc img.tif --out img-srgb.tif
```

I am attempting to automate a process on a Linux cloud computer, and need an equivalent command line (or Python function). I've attempted to use imagemagick convert, but since I don't really understand the problem, I'm having trouble figuring out what I want to tell it to do.

The output of imagemagick identify for this image is as follows:

```
Image: scratch/gcs/src-colors/poly/Orange.tif
  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 5760x3840+0+0
  Resolution: 240x240
  Print size: 24x16
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Type: TrueColor
  Base type: TrueColor
  Endianess: MSB
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Red:
      min: 37 (0.145098)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 161.395 (0.632923)
      standard deviation: 31.9903 (0.125452)
      kurtosis: 0.330666
      skewness: -0.638406
    Green:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 166 (0.65098)
      mean: 56.2109 (0.220435)
      standard deviation: 21.8988 (0.0858777)
      kurtosis: 0.0542889
      skewness: -0.481283
    Blue:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 126 (0.494118)
      mean: 5.63112 (0.0220828)
      standard deviation: 11.5607 (0.045336)
      kurtosis: 2.85701
      skewness: 1.97321
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 74.4125 (0.291814)
      standard deviation: 23.3566 (0.0915944)
      kurtosis: 139.8
      skewness: 13.527
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Interlace: None
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 5760x3840+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: None
  Orientation: TopLeft
  Properties:
    date:create: 2015-12-02T21:47:33+00:00
    date:modify: 2015-12-02T21:47:33+00:00
    exif:ApertureValue: 8.91886
    exif:CustomRendered: 0
    exif:DateTimeDigitized: 2015:09:28 22:50:19
    exif:DateTimeOriginal: 2015:09:28 22:50:19
    exif:ExposureBiasValue: 0
    exif:ExposureMode: 1
    exif:ExposureProgram: 1
    exif:ExposureTime: 0.005
    exif:Flash: 16
    exif:FNumber: 22
    exif:FocalLength: 70
    exif:FocalPlaneResolutionUnit: 3
    exif:FocalPlaneXResolution: 1600
    exif:FocalPlaneYResolution: 1600
    exif:ISOSpeedRatings: 1
    exif:MaxApertureValue: 4
    exif:MeteringMode: 5
    exif:SceneCaptureType: 0
    exif:ShutterSpeedValue: 7.64386
    exif:SubSecTimeDigitized: 00
    exif:WhiteBalance: 1
    signature: bff167961ea4eb45101f9afc4761289d29e88f12cb91913b683aade8b80b4424
    tiff:endian: lsb
    tiff:make: Canon
    tiff:model: Canon EOS 5D Mark III
    tiff:photometric: RGB
    tiff:rows-per-strip: 1
    tiff:software: Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 6.1.1 (Macintosh)
    tiff:timestamp: 2015:10:29 14:49:50
    xmpMM:DerivedFrom: 
  Profiles:
    Profile-8bim: 7774 bytes
    Profile-icc: 560 bytes
      Description: Adobe RGB (1998)
      Manufacturer: Adobe RGB (1998)
      Model: Adobe RGB (1998)
      Copyright: Copyright 1999 Adobe Systems Incorporated
    Profile-iptc: 64 bytes
      City[1,90]: 0x00000000: 254700                                        -%
      unknown[2,0]: 
      Created Date[2,55]: 20150928
      Created Time[2,60]: 225019
      unknown[2,62]: 20150928
      unknown[2,63]: 225019
    Profile-xmp: 11810 bytes
  Artifacts:
    filename: scratch/gcs/src-colors/poly/Orange.tif
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 66.38MB
  Number pixels: 22.12M
  Pixels per second: 32.06MB
  User time: 0.180u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.690
  Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Disclaimer: I'm super unfamiliar with things like color profiles and colorpsaces, so this could obviously be an XY problem. Feel free to suggest a better solution to my underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that appears to have worked for me was to copy the file `/System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/sRGB Profile.icc` from OSX to my linux machine, and then run:

`convert img.tif -profile sRGB\ Profile.icc img-srgb.tif`

Still interested in learning more about the underlying problem and whether there is a better solution though.